# How many possible combinations of four colors, with each having place restrictions?

Tags: derivatives

I've been playing a simple cellphone game recently.
It works as follow:
The player can construct 4 different types of buildings in a square area of
5x5 spaces, each building taking up one unit of space, for a maximum of 25 buildings.
- The blue building houses 100 people and can be placed anywhere.
- The red building houses 500 people, but can only be placed next to an existing blue building
- The green building houses 2500 people, but can only be placed next to both an existing blue and red building.
- The yellow building houses 12500 people, but can only be placed next to a neighboring blue, red and green buildings.

Note that "next to" means north, south, east or west.
I.e. It is impossible to place a yellow building in a corner, as it only has 2 adjacent spaces.

What is the maximum number of people the player can house in the given area?

Comment: I am more interested in the method of calculating the answer than the actual answer, to be honest.

Comment: Sooo can anyone help me out here or can i jsut delete t and go to another site?